# Using links in crontab

Tags: cron

Can I use a link to a file to set a crontab job on it?

I tried the following:

```
$ crontab -e
$ 10***** /path-to-link/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use a link to a file in crontabs - with the same conditions as always e.g.

- the file that the link resolves to must be executable
- it must be able to run within the limted environment provided by `cron`

In fact, many common executable commands are symbolic links - even `/bin/sh` itself:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 11 13:58 /bin/sh -> dash
```

So for example

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
40 * * * * /bin/sh -c 'echo "Hello from $0 (which is actually $(readlink -f $0))"' > /home/steeldriver/cron.out
```

results in

```
$ cat ~/cron.out
Hello from /bin/sh (which is actually /bin/dash)
```

Answer (score 4):

- You should have spaces between the `*`
- Also as mentioned by @steeldriver - you have too many fields

Adding spaces and removing the extra `*` should work:

```
10 * * * * /path-to-link/
```

[More info - how-do I add jobs to cron under linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

> **Example: Run backup cron job script**
>
> If you wished to have a script named `/root/backup.s`h run ***every day at
>   3am***, your crontab entry would look like as follows. First, install
>   your cronjob by running the following command:
>
> ```
> crontab -e
> ```
>
> Append the following entry:
>
> ```
> 0 3 * * * /root/backup.sh
> ```
>
> Save and close the file.
>
> **How do I use operators?**
>
> An operator allows you to specifying multiple values in a field. There
>   are three operators:
>
> - The asterisk (*) : This operator specifies all possible values for a field. For example, an asterisk in the hour time field would be
>     equivalent to every hour or an asterisk in the month field would be
>     equivalent to every month.
> - The comma (,) : This operator specifies a list of values, for example: “1,5,10,15,20, 25”.
> - The dash (-) : This operator specifies a range of values, for example: “5-15” days , which is equivalent to typing
>     “5,6,7,8,9,….,13,14,15” using the comma operator.
> - The separator (/) : This operator specifies a step value, for example: “0-23/” can be used in the hours field to specify command
>     execution every other hour. Steps are also permitted after an
>     asterisk, so if you want to say every two hours, just use */2.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `10 * * * * *` isn't valid in any case (has too many fields)

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks for the comment! I've updated my answer to reflect it

Comment: @JosefKlimuk - Happy to hear that it was helpful.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk - Note: When an answer helped you, please [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it (you can up-vote multiple useful answers). Also, If the answer solved your question, you should choose one answer which answer your question in the best way and [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it